# How can I interrupt a threadPoolExecutor that's being used without a futures.result() or a main thread that's waiting for tasks to be finished?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pandas

I'm reading a lot of data from an external API (google geocoding) and writing it to a local file. I was initially doing this using a single threaded process but have since rewritten it to use multiple threads.

Here's a simplified version of my code

```
input_dataframe = pd.read_excel(input_path)

keyboard_interrupt = False

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        for iterator in range(0, row_count):
            if not keyboard_interrupt:
                try:
                    executor.submit(normalise_one_record, iterator)
                except(KeyboardInterrupt):
                    print("Stopped by user - loop")
                    keyboard_interrupt = True
            else:
                break

input_dataframe.to_excel(output_path)
```

Since I don't want to spam the API, I'm limiting the number of parallel calls I'm making by limiting my workers.

The `normalise_one_record` function does the following:

- Read some info from a row in the dataframe
- Call the API
- Write the API results back to the dataframe, using a lock to prevent concurrent writes

One execution of `normalise_one_record` takes between 0.4 to 1 second(s).

In my single threaded function, it was easy to use a keyboardInterrupt and write my dataframe to a file within the finally block.

From reading docs and other questions, it seems like a keyboard interrupt is only caught within the main thread, but my block executes too quickly to trigger the KeyboardInterrupt.

I've tried adding `try...except` blocks inside the `normalise_one_record` function and its subfunctions, but to no avail.

How can I stop my API calls early and not lose my dataframe results i.e. write them to disk?

I'm a little new to python, only having worked on it for a couple of weeks, so I'm sorry if I'm overlooking any obvious solutions.